# ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'keras'?

Tags: python, keras

```
from keras.models import load_model
```

Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-4ddaf29d467b> in <module>
----> 1 from keras.models import load_model
      2 import cv2
      3 import numpy as np
      4 import tkinter
      5 from tkinter import messagebox

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

Comment: also, please use code block! :(

Comment: Please notice that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (never executed) and it should not be included here as it just creates unnecessary clutter (edited out).

Answer (score 0):

You need to first install `keras` using `pip install keras` or you can use `conda-forge` as in this [link](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/keras).